# How to properly setup a spring application using Spring Cloud K8s to work with k8s secrets using helm?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I have a Spring Boot application where I have the k8s files for deployment, configmaps and secrets. Their values are being updated using helm.
I want to have a `secrets.yaml` where I put the values there and it replaces the values inside my `application.yaml` from Spring Boot. I managed to this for the configmaps. I created the `configmap.yaml`, put the values I want to replace there, setup Spring Cloud K8s to have the permission to execute this (creating the rbac) and it worked. But for the secrets I didn't manage to do this.

Here is my `application.yaml`. I want to replace the `banana.database.password`.

```yaml
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: off
  application:
    name: devops-integration
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      secrets:
        name: devops-integration
        paths: /etc/secrets
banana:
  valueTest: hello
  valueDebug: world
  database:
    password: dGVzdAo=
```

Here is my `secret.yaml`.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
  labels:
    environment: {{ .Values.cloud.project.environment }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    tier: {{ .Values.application.tier }}
data:
  banana.database.password: {{ .Values.application.database.password }}
```

Here is my `values.yaml` with the final value I want for the secret.

```yaml
application:
  name: devops-integration
  database:
    password: dGVzdHBhc3N3b3JkCg==
```

And here is my `deployment.yaml` where I tried to configure mounts for the secrets, but it din't work.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-deployment
  labels:
    environment: {{ .Values.cloud.project.environment }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    tier: {{ .Values.application.tier }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.application.pod.replicas }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      environment: {{ .Values.cloud.project.environment }}
      release: {{ .Release.Name }}
      tier: {{ .Values.application.tier }}
  template:
    metadata:
      namespace: {{ .Values.cloud.project.namespace }}
      labels:
        environment: {{ .Values.cloud.project.environment }}
        release: {{ .Release.Name }}
        tier: {{ .Values.application.tier }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/{{ .Values.cloud.project.name }}/{{ .Values.application.name }}
        name: {{ .Release.Name }}-container
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/etc/secrets"
          name: {{ .Release.Name }}-volume
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.application.pod.container.port }}
          protocol: {{ .Values.application.pod.container.protocol }}
      volumes:
      - name: {{ .Release.Name }}-volume
        secret:
          secretName: {{ .Release.Name }}
```

When I deploy everything, what happens is that the value for the password is the one inside the `application.yaml`, not the one that the `secret.yaml` is using. For the configmaps this same pattern worked.

Does someone know what could I have done wrong?

PS.: Everything will be deployed to GKE.

Comment: Which version of `helm` do you use?

Comment: I am very confused of what worked and what not and what are you trying to do, at all. If you have a secret (it is entirely irrelevant how if you use helm or not) and you need some properties from that secret exposed to your spring application - then your approach is entirely wrong.

Comment: I'm using helm v3.
What I want is that I don'w want to set every secret inside the deployment file, one by one.

Comment: if you want to notify the users under your question, you need to tag them with `@`, otherwise I have no idea you posted a comment. Your last comment makes no sense in the context of your question. Let's work this out in reverse. Do you have a `secrets.yaml` file and want to expose all of its data as spring properties so that you could use them via `@ConfigurationProperties`, for example? And I will also repeat that using (or not) `helm` for this is irrelevant.

Comment: @Eugene sorry, it's my first time working with k8s and helm. I want the values from my `secrets.yaml` to replace the values inside the spring properties. I managed to this this for the `configmap.yaml`, but for the secrets it didn't work

Comment: Do you need it in _both_ application properties and secrets.yaml? Helm is a way to deploy some manifests to k8s, but its not they only one. Spring does not care how they end up in k8s, all it cares is the ability to read such files. If you do not need them in application.properties and you will read then always from secrets.yaml, then Ill show you how to do it.